# Basic ActionScript Help?

Tags: actionscript

I have a MXML file and ActionScript Class...

Now i have a component textInput in my MXML, how would i call this in my ActionScript class.

```
<mx:TextInput styleName="loginTextInput" id="username" x="160" y="161"/>
```

ActionScript class..

```
package myClasses
{

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent; 
    public class CheckLogin
    {
        public function CheckLogin()
        {
        }

        private function loginCheck():void {
            // I need to call the TextInput down here.
        Alert.show("loginCheck Done");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it by using the 'id' of the mxml-component... so for example `username.text = "whatever";`

Answer (score 0):

you need let mxml and as3 class file know each other.
in myClass file, you need a reference to the TextInput that 'id="username"'.
how? I should change loginCheck function access propoerty from "private" to "public" :

```
public function loginCheck(username:TextInput):void
{
    // trace(username.text);
    // do some thing you like to do.
    Alert.show("loginCheck Done");
}
```

and in mxml file you should mod it to

```
...
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
       public function callme(e:MouseEvent):void
      {
          var checker:myClass = new myClass();
          checker.loginCheck(username);
      }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
       <mx:TextInput styleName="loginTextInput" id="username" x="160" y="161"/>
       <s:Button label="check" click="callme"/>
...
```

this link [would](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7fff.html) help

Answer (score 0):

MXML:

```
<mx:TextInput styleName="loginTextInput" id="username" text="@{model.username}" x="160" y="161"/>
```

AS:

```
package myClasses
{

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent; 
public class CheckLogin
{

    private var _username:String;

    [Bindable]
    public function get userName():String {
        return this._username;
    }

    public function set userName(value:String):void {
        this._username = value;
    }

    public function CheckLogin()
    {
    }

    private function loginCheck():void {
        // I need to call the TextInput down here.
        // access the Textinput by using this._username
    Alert.show("loginCheck Done");
    }


}
}
```